# How get object from list with given id from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component **Sound**, which receives from props:

- audioId
- audios

I want to find in array object with given audioId, unfortunatelly my code does not work (my variable **this.AUDIO** is undefined). Can you tell me why?

This is what my props look like:

[image]

---

```
class Sound extends Component {

    AUDIO = this.props.audios.find((sound) => {
        return sound.audioDto.id === this.props.audioId;
    });

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>{this.AUDIO.audioDto.id}</h1>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Sound;
```

Comment: Why don't you access it directly from props? Or you could store it in state as well.

Comment: That looks like it should work, provided `id` and `audioId` are of the same type (rather than `id` being a number and `audioId` being a string, for instance). Please show us an example of the objects in the `audios` array and confirm the types of the IDs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder click HERE button in my post

Comment: @costamumiemalenic - Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: As far as one can tell from the question, again, that should work. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

Move this code

```
AUDIO = this.props.audios.find((sound) => {
        return sound.audioDto.id === this.props.audioId;
    });
```

Inside render function.

```
class Sound extends Component {

    render() {
        let AUDIO = this.props.audios.find((sound) => {
           return sound.audioDto.id === this.props.audioId;
        });
        return (
            <h1>
                {AUDIO.audioDto.id}
            </h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Sound;
```